# Javascript - Set a 'let' variable from another module in browser

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, constants, let

Specifically I'm testing this in the latest version of Google Chrome, but I suspected this would be the same in Edge/Firefox/Safari (Last I was aware Edge and Firefox had modules hidden in experimental javascript flags)

In a 'globals.js' I have a let scale.

```
// inside global.js
let scale = 1;
```

In another module, I wanted to adjust the scale

```
// inside another js file
import { scale } from "../JS/globals.js";
scale = Math.min( scale + ((scale + delta) * speed), target);
```

But I'm getting error "Assignment to constant variable".

I imagined one obvious way to do this, is to export a function named set_scale

```
// back in globals.js
export function set_scale (value) { scale = value };
```

And I have already done this for a few other variables from globals.js.
But I wanted to know if anyone has any other methods for overcoming exports/importing lets as constants, especially if it will allow me to avoid making more things to export/import.

Comment: What module loader are you using.  If I was doing this with node.js (common.js).. Inside global.js I would have `module.exports = {scale: 1};`.  Then if I wanted to change.. `const g = require("./globals"); g.scale = ...`

Comment: Its in chrome. They recently enabled export+import in the actual browser.

I'm not initially aware if it works in firefox or edge yet, but as far as I'm aware, safari already implemented it and the other browsers were hiding modules behind experimental flags, chrome until recently also kept it hidden in their canary browser but now its available in the latest version.

Sorry I forgot about this, I'll update the question to specify this is a question for browsers.

Comment: You should be able to do the same, but using the new ES6 syntax, rather than common.js.  Also -> `scale =` you can't just do that, were does it get `scale` from?.  you more than likely wanted `global.scale`.. That probably why you get the error.

Comment: scale is already imported from globals.js
    import { scale } from "../JS/globals.js"
So I can read it, but the reference seems to be a constant despite declared as a let.

Comment: You can't do that.. That import will be equivalent to `const scale = globals.scale`,  access from the object level, and you will be ok..

Comment: Do you mean to use "import * as Globals from "global.js""? It's giving me read only properties still.

Comment: I would do -> `export default { scale: 1}` and `import global from "global"`  and then use like `global.scale = ....`

Comment: export default does the trick, a good answer for this problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do as following in your globals.js file:

```
export default {scale: 1}
```

and in the other modules, use it like this:

```
import global from "global" 

global.scale = ...
... = global.scale
```